# Confirmed transaction in Mist wallet multisig but it never goes away

Tags: mist, wallets

I sent a transaction between two of my my wallets back in July. I confirmed the transaction and the Ether was sent. All is well. The only thing is the transaction continues to show at the top of my Mist Ethereum Wallet as pending. Any ideas how I can get rid of the "Confirmation Needed" notification?

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Confirmed, Ether successfully sent, but Mist UI shows it as pending]